# How to Use interface IValueEventListener in object DatabaseReference Xamarin.Firebase.Database?

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new in C# Xamarin. I have a sample Java class here (from [this tutorial](https://github.com/crazyhitty/firebase-chat)). It's difficult to me to implement ValueEventListener in C# using xamarin.firebase.database. Would you like to help me? Thank you.

```
public class ChatInteractor implements ChatContract.Interactor {
    private static final String TAG = "ChatInteractor";

    @Override
    public void sendMessageToFirebaseUser(final Context context, final Chat chat, final String receiverFirebaseToken) {

        final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    databaseReference.child(Constants.ARG_CHAT_ROOMS).getRef().addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void getMessageFromFirebaseUser(String senderUid, String receiverUid) {

    final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    databaseReference.child(Constants.ARG_CHAT_ROOMS).getRef().addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: thanks @AL for editing

Answer (score 4):

First of all: do you have a Xamarin Android Binding for the `Firebase Android SDK`? If you don't, you can't really follow any Java-Android tutorial, since the Firebase specific classes / interfaces won't exist. If that's the case: install https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Database/

If you do - implement the interface like that:
(inline implementations - like you can do in java; and it's done in your example - are not supported in C#. So you'll have to create a regular class)

```
   public class MyValueEventListener : Java.Lang.Object, Firebase.Database.IValueEventListener
    {

        public void OnCancelled(DatabaseError error)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
```

and pass it as an eventlistener

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.Instance.Reference;
        databaseReference.Child(Constants.ARG_CHAT_ROOMS).Ref.AddListenerForSingleValueEvent(new MyValueEventListener())
```

Comment: ok @woelliJ. And then how I use parameters of method getMessageFromFirebaseUser(String senderUid, String receiverUid) in class MyValueEventListener?

Comment: I don't see how that method is used in your example code. You could pass all kinds of handlers or whatever through the constructor of 'MyValueEventListener'.